# Cakephp2: How to call and use the function in a Model in Controller

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I'm new to Cakephp2 and I wanted to ask a question to the pros.
How to call a function in model in a controller in cakephp2? I've read the documentation but
it's not clear to me since I'm a newbie.It would be great if I can attain clear explanation! Thank you!

For example I have a model named Android and in that model there is a function

```
public  function _checkUaType($ua) {

}
```

Should I call the function like `$this->Android->_checkUaType($ua)` ? Or are there a better way to use a function in a controller?

Comment: thats correct..if you loaded the `Android` Model in your controller

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that is there a right way to call the model into the controller? Seems like there is multiple ways to call the model. If there is a example that will be great!

Comment: you can just load the model in the controller using `$this->loadModel('Android')` then use `$this->Android->_checkUaType($ua)` in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just load the model in the controller and call Model function as below example.

In the Controller use below code:

```
function YourFunctionName {
    $this->loadModel('Android');
    $this->Android->_checkUaType($ua);
}
```